# Equivalent of string contains in google bigquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a table like as shown below

[image]

I would like to create `two new binary columns` indicating whether the subject had `steroids` and `aspirin`. I am looking to implement this in `Postgresql and google bigquery`

I tried the below but it doesn't work

```
select subject_id
case when lower(drug) like ('%cortisol%','%cortisone%','%dexamethasone%') 
then 1 else 0 end as steroids,
case when lower(drug) like ('%peptide%','%paracetamol%') 
then 1 else 0 end as aspirin,
from db.Team01.Table_1


SELECT 
db.Team01.Table_1.drug
FROM `table_1`,
UNNEST(table_1.drug) drug
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS( db.Team01.Table_1.drug,r'%cortisol%','%cortisone%','%dexamethasone%')
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  subject_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(drug), r'cortisol|cortisone|dexamethasone') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS steroids,
  SUM(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(drug), r'peptide|paracetamol') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aspirin
FROM `db.Team01.Table_1`
GROUP BY subject_id
```

if to apply to sample data from your question  - result is

```
Row subject_id  steroids    aspirin  
1   1           3           1    
2   2           1           1
```

Note: instead of simple LIKE ending with lengthy and redundant text - I am using `LIKE on steroids` - which is [REGEXP_CONTAINS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains)

Answer (score 4):

In Postgres, I would recommend using the `filter` clause:

```
select subject_id,
       count(*) filter (where lower(drug) ~ 'cortisol|cortisone|dexamethasone') as steroids,
       count(*) filter (where lower(drug) ~ 'peptide|paracetamol') as aspirin,
from db.Team01.Table_1
group by subject_id;
```

In BigQuery, I would recommend `countif()`:

```
select subject_id,
       countif(regexp_contains(drug, 'cortisol|cortisone|dexamethasone') as steroids,
       countif(drug ~ ' 'peptide|paracetamol') as aspirin,
from db.Team01.Table_1
group by subject_id;
```

You can use `sum(case when . . . end)` as a more general approach.  However, each database has a more "local" way of expressing this logic.  By the way, the `FILTER` clause *is* standard SQL, just not widely adopted.

Comment: 'countif()' is an aggregation function,and its more resource consuming. and it seems this code wont work `countif(drug ~ ' 'peptide|paracetamol')`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, can you help me with using `%` symbol in your statement? `where regexp_contains(drug,'(?i)dexamethasone'|'(?i)cortisone'|'(?i)cortisol') -- This looks for string presence in the `drug` column. But what if I like to find whether items that ends with `%sone` or starts with `corti` exist `ALONG WITH THE CONTAINS CONDITION`.  Is it something like this `WHERE LOWER(CAST(DRUG AS BYTES)) LIKE b'corti%'
  OR LOWER(CAST(DRUG AS BYTES)) LIKE b'%sone' 
  OR regexp_contains(drug,'(?i)dexamethasone'|'(?i)cortisone'|'(?i)cortisol')`

Comment: @SSMK . . . `%` is not needed, in either database.  Perhaps you should ask another question, if you want to specifically use `like` for this.

Answer (score 4):

I've not used BigQuery but have been reading the docs researching it. I came across this while looking into impact of choosing collation at design stage.

I'm either wrong or this is a new feature since answers above.

#### CONTAINS_SUBSTR

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#contains_substr

> Performs a normalized, case-insensitive search to see if a value
> exists as a substring in an expression. Returns TRUE if the value
> exists, otherwise returns FALSE.
>
> Before values are compared, they are normalized and case folded with
> NFKC normalization. Wildcard searches are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation. This is a solution that works across most (if not all) RDBMS:

```
SELECT
    subject_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN drug IN ('cortisol', 'cortisone', 'dexamethasone') THEN 1 END) steroids,
    MAX(CASE WHEN drug IN ('peptide', 'paracetamol') THEN 1 END) aspirin
FROM db.Team01.Table_1.drug
GROUP BY subject_id
```

NB: it is unclear why you are using `LIKE`, since it seems like you are having exact matches; I turned the `LIKE` condition to equalities.

Comment: But no, `steroid` is a column that I have to create. I have to use the values like `cortisol`,`cortsione` etc. If you check my query in post, you will get an idea

Comment: Do you know what doesn't it work with `Like` operator? Does it support only `IN` clause in `case when`

Comment: I think `IN` should be supported. If not, you can switch to `OR`ed equalities, like; ` drug = 'peptide' OR drug = 'paracetamol'`.

Answer (score 1):

you have missing `group-by`

```
select subject_id,
    sum(case when lower(drug) in ('cortisol','cortisone','dexamethasone')
       then 1 else 0 end) as steroids,
    sum(case when lower(drug) in ('peptide','paracetamol') 
       then 1 else 0 end) as aspirin
from db.Team01.Table_1
group by subject_id
```

using `like` keyword

```
select subject_id,
 sum(case when lower(drug) like '%cortisol%'
        or lower(drug) like '%cortisone%'
        or lower(drug) like '%dexamethasone%'   
    then 1 else 0 end) as steroids,
    sum(case when lower(drug) like '%peptide%'
        or lower(drug) like '%paracetamol%'
    then 1 else 0 end) as aspirin
from db.Team01.Table_1
group by subject_id
```

Comment: i used sum() because i think, this is what your trying to achieve

Comment: I encounter this error `No matching signature for operator LIKE for argument types: STRING, STRUCT. Supported signatures: STRING LIKE STRING; BYTES LIKE BYTES at [2:19]`

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't support `Like` operatir?

Comment: added using like operator

Comment: try also `lower(drug) similar to '%(cortisol|cortisone|dexamethasone)%'`

Comment: Is `similar to` there in bigquery?

Comment: only in postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Another potentially more intutive solution would be to use the [BigQuery Contains_Substr](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#contains_substr)
to return boolean results.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31135860)